# Highlight country flag on blank world map when hovered on specific country

Tags: dictionary, svg, flags, country, jvectormap

I'm using [jVectormap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/) plugin for country highlighting on world map. Now As my question suggests i want to show country's flag when specific country is hovered over.

I don't want to do image mapping for whole world map. so don't post that solution, i don't think its a feasible solution as i don't have such time to do that.

if anybody has done this functionality using any plugin, svg, google maps, js anything please help me out.

If any paid plugin is there even then i would like to know. I have searched for 2 days. But i haven't come across such functionality yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945265/add-click-event-on-elements-of-an-embedded-svg-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

You can provide a function for [`onRegionLabelShow`](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/) that uses the region `code` to construct a URL for the country flag and then customize the `label`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code)
        {
           label.html(label.html()+
           '<br><img src="'+getFlagImgSrc(code)+'" height="20">');
        }
    });

    /*
    * Constructs a URL for a country flag image on Flags Of The World 
    * using the ISO-3166 Digraph 
    */
    function getFlagImgSrc(code)
    {
       return 'http://www.fotw.us/images/'+
               code.toLowerCase().substring(0,1)+
               '/'+
               code.toLowerCase()+
               '.gif';  
    }    

});​
```

An example of how the rendered label looks with the country flag when you mouse over a region:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me is it possible for you to look at this question too?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672204/jvector-map-how-to-have-dynamic-images-when-markers-hover

Comment: The function `onRegionLabelShow` is renamed `onRegionTipShow` in v2.0+