# jvectormap: How to implement HTML instead of simple string in the markers label/tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, tooltip, jvectormap

I've just implemented the jQuery plugin **[jvectormap](http://jvectormap.com/)**, for the use of a world map. Everything's working perfectly, except this maybe..
I added a few markers and have been trying to implement HTML to the markers label/tooltip.
So instead of just "blabla" I want an image/html to show up, when hovering the marker.

How can I achieve this result?

**Here's the initializing JS:**

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [46.90, 8.45], name: "<img src=\"img/logo.png\">"}
    ],
...(other code isn't important)...
```

The important part is **`name: "<img src=\"img/logo.png\">"`**

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to customize the label/tooltip that is displayed when you mouse over the marker, you should provide a function for **[onMarkerLabelShow](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/)**.

> **onMarkerLabelShow**    Function `(Event e, Object label, String code)` Will be called right before the marker label is going to be shown.

For example:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [46.90, 8.45], name: "My marker name"}
    ],
    onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
     label.html("<img src=\"img/logo.png\"><br>"+ label.html());                
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice, got it working for 1 label! :)
So how can I differenciate between two labels in the "onMarkerLabelShow" function?

Comment: `code` will return the `name` for that marker in the `onMarkerLabelShow()` function. Check out this example of how to display a country flag image when hovering over a region, same technique could be applied for markers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769847/14419

Comment: onMarkerLabelShow is deprecated for now, onMarkerTipShow function with same params is instead.

Comment: Nice @MadsHansen. How to display  database value  in label ? when i click country? i trying last two weeks i cant get answer pls help me

Comment: @Thennarasu Ideally try retrieving the database value via an AJAX call within the `onMarkerLabelShow` function. You need something like this: `var dbValue; $.ajax({ url: "database.php", success: function(data) { dbValue = data; } });`