# Jvectormap add text inside the markers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, jvectormap

I am using the latest Jvectormap (1.2.2), but can't find any examples of adding text inside markers.
I want to display the count inside marker for respective countries.

Below is the code i have written for displaying the markers.

```
$ ->
  $('#world-map').vectorMap
    map: "world_mill_en"
    scaleColors: ["#C8EEFF", "#0071A4"]
    backgroundColor: 'white'
    regionStyle:
      initial:
        fill: "#D4D4D4"
    markerStyle:
      initial:
        fill: "rgb(202,219,42)"
        stroke: "#383f47"
    markers: $("input#map_marker").data("values")
```

Im current generating marker data in controller and storing it in hidden field which i pass to the jvectormap.

The data is as follows

```
[{"name":"Algeria","latLng":[27.2257,2.49295],"weburl":"/en/browse?country_ids=1","count":45,"id":1},
{"name":"Angola","latLng":[-11.2027,17.8739],"weburl":"/en/browse?country_ids=2","count":46,"id":2},
{"name":"Benin","latLng":[9.30769,2.31583],"weburl":"/en/browse?country_ids=3","count":43,"id":3},
{"name":"Botswana","latLng":[-22.3285,24.6849],"weburl":"/en/browse?country_ids=4","count":42,"id":4}]
```

Im able to get the marker on the screen i just wanted to add the count value inside these markers.

Thanks in advance for anyone taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onMarkerLabelShow`.

Here's another related SO question: [jvectormap: How to implement HTML instead of simple string in the markers label/tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937946/jvectormap-how-to-implement-html-instead-of-simple-string-in-the-markers-label)

Comment: onMarkerLabelShow would show text on the label whereas i need it to be on the marker itself