# markerStyle in JVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to style the markers from http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/ but I'm having difficult time applying the background image for the markers

background attribute isn't working here, any directions for this?

```
markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47',
        background: 'url("image.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 transparent'
      }
    },
```

Comment: I found the solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937946/jvectormap-how-to-implement-html-instead-of-simple-string-in-the-markers-label?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the alternative option

[jvectormap: How to implement HTML instead of simple string in the markers label/tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937946/jvectormap-how-to-implement-html-instead-of-simple-string-in-the-markers-label?rq=1)

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [46.90, 8.45], name: "My marker name"}
    ],
    onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
     label.html("<img src=\"img/logo.png\"><br>"+ label.html());                
    }
});
```