# node-webkit <object> onmousedown

Tags: javascript, svg, node-webkit

I have a frameless window with a titlebar set up much like in the [node-webkit sample apps](https://github.com/zcbenz/nw-sample-apps) (that is, with buttons that have `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` so that they accept user input).

Because I'd like my app to be completely themeable, I decided to implement the minimize/maximize/close buttons as SVG and manipulate their color/opacity through JavaScript.

### Example

As an example, I have the following close button `close.svg`:

```
<svg class="close-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="26">
    <g>
        <title>Close</title>
        <path class="close-icon-bg" fill="#c8c8c8" d="M0 0h30v26h-30z"/>
        <path class="close-icon-fg" d="M11.766 8l-1.766 1.766 3.221 3.221-3.221 3.247 1.766 1.766 3.221-3.247 3.247 3.247 1.766-1.766-3.247-3.247 3.247-3.221-1.766-1.766-3.247 3.221-3.221-3.221z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I then have the following in my titlebar div:

```
<object id="close-btn" data="img/close.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Then in JavaScript I have the following:

```
function refreshTheme(theme) {

    var but2 = {
        "default": {
            "bg": {"color": "#000000", "opacity": "0.0"},
            "fg": {"color": "#000000", "opacity": "0.2"}
        },
        "hover": {
            "bg": {"color": "#ac4142", "opacity": "1.0"},
            "fg": {"color": "#e0e0e0", "opacity": "1.0"}
        },
        "click": {
            "bg": {"color": "#000000", "opacity": "1.0"},
            "fg": {"color": "#e0e0e0", "opacity": "1.0"}
        }
    };

    createButton("close", but2, dummy);
}

function createButton(name, theme, func) {
    var svgobj = document.getElementById(name + "-btn"), svg = svgobj.contentDocument;

    styleIcon(svg, name, theme.default);

    svgobj.onmouseover = function() {
        styleIcon(svg, name, theme.hover);
    };

    svgobj.onmouseout = function() {
        styleIcon(svg, name, theme.default);
    };

    svgobj.onmousedown = function() {
        styleIcon(svg, name, theme.click);
    };

    svgobj.onclick = function() {
        func();
    };
}

function styleIcon(icon, name, theme) {
    var bg = icon.getElementsByClassName(name + "-icon-bg")[0];
    bg.setAttribute("fill", theme.bg.color);
    bg.setAttribute("fill-opacity", theme.bg.opacity);

    var fg = icon.getElementsByClassName(name + "-icon-fg")[0];
    fg.setAttribute("fill", theme.fg.color);
    fg.setAttribute("fill-opacity", theme.fg.opacity);
}
```

Essentially what happens is, I have a hard-coded JSON object `but2` encapsulating the button states, which I pass to `createButton()`, which is responsible for setting up the various mouse events. I can confirm that the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events work well:

[image: Above is onmouseout, below is onmouseover]

The top screenshot shows `onmouseout`, the bottom `onmouseover`.

### The Problem

What *doesn't* work are the `onmousedown` and `onclick` events! They appear to be set up correctly in the debug window and no errors are present in the console, but they never get fired.

I was under the impression that `<object>` tags accept all standard HTML events, so this should work. Is there something I'm missing? Some node-webkit caveat maybe? Something to do with SVG's?

How can I get the `onmousedown` and `onclick` events to fire properly?

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward will this work in jsfiddle? I tried editing locally (i.e. not in node-webkit) but Chrome complains at the `svg = svgobj.contentDocument;` part since I'm going cross-document. But sure, I'll set one up

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Doesn't seem to work at all in jsfiddle, but you can play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff6pa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an actual problem with SVG's in browsers. The solution, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296097/making-an-svg-image-object-clickable-with-onclick-avoiding-absolute-positioning), is to have the *SVG* hold the mouse up/down/click events in a transparent (`fill-opacity="0.0"`) rectangle spanning the whole image.

In my case, the solution was:

```
var svg_click = svg.getElementsByClassName(name + "-icon-click")[0];

svg_click.onmousedown = function() {
    styleIcon(svg, name, theme.click);
};

// etc...
```

I'm not terribly pleased with it, considering it should also work from the `<object>` tag, but hey...it's still a solution.