# How can I make images that overlap hoverable and clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, svg

I am working on a model of a human body, which has specific organs that need to highlight and come to the top on hover and be clickable.  The hard part, ex:  The lungs overlap the heart, how can I make the heart clickable without putting it on top of the lungs?

[image]

I tried using transparent SVGs, but haven't been able to get them to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: If its svg, couldn't you just put css pointer-events: none on the bits you don't want to be clickable ?

Answer (score 3):

You need a "hit-test" mechanism. It works like this:

1. keep contours of your shapes in a JS structure
2. have a single surface on your graphics receive all mouse click events
3. when the surface is clicked, use the passed coords to find which shape got hit in (1)

---

Alternatively, switching your graphics into vectors will provide this functionality [out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055147/314056), but the added advantage of scalable graphics. The downsides to this are: old browsers and increased processing to generate the vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the outline paths of the heart, lungs, etc?

If yes, you just use `context.isPointInPath` to hit-test each of your organs.

If no, you can draw each organ onto its own canvas and then use `context.getImageData` to hit-test whether the pixel under the mouse is opaque for any particular organ-canvas.

Here's an example of hit-testing with the pixel data:

[image]

Highlighting the organ the mouse is hovering:

[image][image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;


var heartCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var heartCtx=heartCanvas.getContext('2d');
var lungsCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var lungsCtx=lungsCanvas.getContext('2d');
heartCanvas.width=lungsCanvas.width=canvas.width;
heartCanvas.height=lungsCanvas.height=canvas.height;
var heart={canvas:heartCanvas,x:100,y:125,alpha:0.25};
var lungs={canvas:lungsCanvas,x:65,y:105,alpha:0.25};

var imgCount=3;
var bodyImg=new Image();bodyImg.onload=start;bodyImg.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/humanOutline.png";
var heartImg=new Image();heartImg.crossOrigin='anonymous';heartImg.onload=start;heartImg.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/heart.png";
var lungsImg=new Image();lungsImg.crossOrigin='anonymous';lungsImg.onload=start;lungsImg.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/lungs.png";
function start(){
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}   
  var data;
  heartCtx.drawImage(heartImg,heart.x,heart.y);
  data=heartCtx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  heart.pixels=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){heart.pixels.push(data[i+3]);}
  lungsCtx.drawImage(lungsImg,lungs.x,lungs.y);
  data=lungsCtx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  lungs.pixels=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){lungs.pixels.push(data[i+3]);}
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  draw();
}

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
  ctx.drawImage(bodyImg,0,0);
  ctx.globalAlpha=heart.alpha;
  ctx.drawImage(heartCanvas,0,0);
  ctx.globalAlpha=lungs.alpha;
  ctx.drawImage(lungsCanvas,0,0);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var heartPixelAlpha=heart.pixels[mouseY*cw+mouseX];
  heart.alpha=(heartPixelAlpha>0)?1.00:0.25;
  var lungsPixelAlpha=lungs.pixels[mouseY*cw+mouseX];
  lungs.alpha=(lungsPixelAlpha>0)?1.00:0.25;

  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Hover mouse over 1+ organs to highlight them</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=330></canvas>
```

Comment: It almost works perfectly... moving over the part of the lungs which cover the heart triggers the event for both organs.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make the design decision about what happens when hovering over multiple organs--my example highlights both. If you want to highlight just a single organ you could order your hit tests in your desired z-index order and then stop testing after reaching your first hit.