# How does SVG click event handling differ between browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, cross-browser

I noticed that browser's behavior is very inconsistent across implementations and operating systems.

E.g., When there is an icon withing a link,

```
<a href="faq.html" class="icn icn-faq">
    <svg version="1.1" role="img" aria-label="FAQ">
        <use xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#faq" />
    </svg>
</a>
```

which works regardless of where one clicks.  However, if I add a (jQuery based) lightbox `jQuery('a.icn-faq').fancybox({"content": "wat?"})`, browser behaviour starts to differ.  Clicks anywhere on the SVG cause the lightbox to appear in all browsers except for Safari, where it only works if one doesn't hit a `path`.

I learned that I can fix this by [adding a transparent `rect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210322/2425163), which gives me consistent browser behavior again.

```
<a href="faq.html" class="icn icn-faq">
    <svg version="1.1" role="img" aria-label="FAQ">
        <use xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#faq" />
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" />
    </svg>
</a>
```

I also know about [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).  Setting `pointer-events: none` for the SVG breaks click-events on OS X but doesn't seem to affect Linux browsers

I'm lacking understanding of how it all fits together.  What are the underlying principles which cause these differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this question, just varying levels of bugginess in browsers (though it mostly works nowadays).

The fancybox behavior seems to be caused by a [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11352) which only occurs in certain browsers.  It can be fixed with an simple `pointer-events: none`.

Understanding the behavior in details doesn't buy one much.  It's useful to know about how to work around these issues (add a image filling path like shown in the question).  The rest are browser implementation details and not worth the pain for most people.