# Auto Click Script on Page load

Tags: javascript

I need a help creating a Java Script code for Browser  console

That would auto click the Follow button or click on SVG icon

e.g. [https://www.zomato.com/users/anuradha-biswas-285812502/network] it should auto click on followers atonce or click all follow ( SVG icon) on page load.

Thanks in advance.
I am newbie

Auto click script for followers.

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: Please remove the java tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the JS function called by body onload event, do the following:

document.getElementById("theIdOfTheFollowButton").click();

For an svg do the [first answer here to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296097/making-an-svg-image-object-clickable-with-onclick-avoiding-absolute-positioning) is clickable.

Comment: Hi!! I want to follow these user by Using query.  Follow Button is indeed a SVG icon and I want follow at once with single click.

Comment: Updated answer for svg.

Comment: Why don’t you call the follow function directly from body onload?